# How to factor $(1-(i^2/n)(1/n)$ to isolate $i^2$ and form a sigma identity?

Tags: summation, factoring, area, riemann-sum

given sigma from $i=1$ to $n$ of $(1-(i^2/n)^2)(1/n))$

how would you factor this function to isolate $i^2$ and get $[n(n+1)(2n+1)]/6$ ?

update... I got until the limit as n approaches infinity (1/n) sigma from i=1 to n (1-(i^2/n^2))

I still am unable to factor out (1-(i^2/n^2)) outside the sigma and just leave i^2 inside the sigma function.

Comment: There is a ")" missing in the title equation.

Comment: How do you want to get that isolating something that is an running index??

Comment: I should probably add that I am trying to find the limit as n approaches infinity of this riemann sum.

Comment: do you want to find a formula?

Comment: My goal is to find an equation A(area) = lim n-->infinity of sigma 1 to n of (i^2).